# RRD fine tuning

Tags: linux, performance, rrdtool, rrd

I have used RRD few months back , for my large application where is in I was running around 5k RRD update from my application resulting in huge I?O at  my box.

I tried many things to improve the performance , but IO and corresponding load just forced me to move to flat files .

Are there any guide lines to use RRD at such level where you requires around 10k RRD/minute.

Is there and fine tuning guide for RRD?

P.S. I did this exercise on Linux box.

Thanks,
Jain

Answer (score 1):

you must usa a) recent rrdtool (1.4.8) and b) make sure there is sufficient ram on the box so that the hot blocks of all rrds can be cached ... if you do testing, you should see that performance drops drastically as soon as you are over the cache limit. 10k/minute should be no problem at all.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion , i do like to try this , but i like to highlight that in  my case I?O was peaking and load average too.
will cross check with the latest version ....

Comment: the question is if io is peaking form write alone or if there is also a lot of read ... if you have read, you need more ram